# pad string with spaces

Tags: string, whitespace

I cannot figure out how to add spaces before or after a string, and then store the padded string in a variable. Printing to console works fine, but when I try to assign the result of the `printf` to a variable then the spaces disappear. For example:

```
TEST='blah'
PAD=$(printf "%5s" $TEST)
echo $PAD
```

yields `blah` without any leading spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like this behavior was a bug in an older version of `zsh`. In version 5.8, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

the wrong is the last `echo $PAD` without quotes.

```
$ TEST=' blah '
$ echo a"$TEST"a
a blah a
```

Comment: As a complement to the answer. This is the correct code:
`TEST='blah'
PAD=$(printf "%5s" $TEST)
echo "$PAD"`